# How to make a .pkg that the Mac Installer will simply install (copy) files from?

Tags: xcode, macos, file, installation, copy

My goal is to create a .pkg that will simply instruct the Mac Installer to simply install files, like fonts, from the .pkg to a directory when run. I've tried using Xcode, but it seems more application oriented.

How do I configure Xcode with a generic document so I can Build and Archive, then Share using the Organizer to create the .pkg?

The Copy Files Target appears to be in use only at build time, so that doesn't seem to be much help.

Comment: For xcode, its easy to make packages! All you do is click create new package and it will let you edit it. Xcode download: [Click Here] (http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Answer (score 13):

You should use the PackageMaker application, not Xcode. You can find it under /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

Comment: Just discovered that it won't work. To get my font collections in the Mac App Store I see I need to use Xcode and the Organizer.
 
How can I use Xcode if I don't actually have any "code" app to sign, other than the PostScript or OpenType scripts contained within the fonts? I assume I would use the Copy Files Target, but what would get signed? How would I build it?

Comment: This tool now has to be separately downloaded. You can get it from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=packagemaker

Comment: @downbeat I'm not certain you CAN just upload a collection of fonts to the app store. Whilst the app stores seem to have a few things like "350 free fonts" etc, they seem to include some sort of preview or organization app to justify calling it an "app". Apples pretty big on insisting that any app sold in its appstores enable functionality. Fonts are not functionality, but rather typography assets.