# Creating an OSX installer

Tags: macos, installation

I want to create an installer that will install a few packages, setup a few directories and run a command as a daemon on OS X.

Do you have any suggestions on how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use the Apple installer ?

Comment: duplicate of @4588283 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588283/how-to-make-a-pkg-that-the-mac-installer-will-simply-install-copy-files-from

Comment: @user510083 not exact - it's a separate download now.

Comment: But even if it shipped separately now, the question is still the same. So maybe you should add your answer to that 'old' question for people who search the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PackageMaker.app -- it's a separate download from Xcode, but available in the DevCenter.